# Routing not working in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I started a new laravel 5.4 project and the routing doesn't seem to work.

My routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/veilingen'], function(){
   Route::resource('/', 'VeilingController');
});
```

php artisan route:list :

[image]

Whenever i populate a URL:

```
<a href="{{ url('/veilingen/' . $veiling->id) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-product">
```

i got this error:
[image]

What am i doing wrong? i was doing it like this all the time and it worked in previous versions.

Comment: Where is your `id` parameter in this line `Route::resource('/', 'VeilingController');` there is just only `/`

Comment: @SagarGautam this wasn't needed in previous versions

Comment: What you want to do using this anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

Found it...
Had to define like this:

```
Route::resource('veilingen','VeilingController');
Route::group(['prefix' => '/veilingen'], function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's enough
`Route::resource('veilingen', 'VeilingController');`

Comment: that is what im doing

Comment: prefix of /veilingen and within Route::resource('/', 'VeilingController');

Comment: I know but in you route:list didn't show parameter. If you use in prefix I think you need specify all route case you use.

Comment: Yes thank you for your help i fixed it now check my answer below

Comment: @JordyGroote Congrats :D